# What does LSI stand for in Battery Monitoring?

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging

After browsing various battery monitoring IC's I have found the term LSI used commonly, without explanation of what the abbreviation stands for. If anyone has any idea what LSI may stand for, please let me know!

Comment: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/2368/large-scale-integration-lsi#:~:text=Large%2Dscale%20integration%20(LSI)%20is%20the%20process%20of%20integrating,processor%20microchips%20were%20under%20development  - does this clarify your question, or is there any detail that you may want to know about in a full answer?

Comment: Though I'm not sure why that would be a selling/marketing point for battery monitoring.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the correct abbreviation. Where I have seen it referenced, it's as though they're referring to the IC as `LSI`, sort of like one would refer to an accelerometer as an IMU.

Comment: [Here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/LC709203F_D-2315014.pdf) is an example of an IC that uses this abbreviation:

Comment: Maybe these components/assemblies were first developed by the old LSI Logic company.  And to the moniker "LSI" was referring to the comapny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have often noticed this on various ICs from ON-semi.
It stands for Large Scale Integration, and I've always considered it similar to Application Specific Integrated Circuit (ASIC).

I don't think LSIs are used/called that anymore, and as for the term still being used by ON Semi, I attributed it to the company wanting to call their own semiconductors something like the household term of "chips", or more specifically "Microchips", but not wanting to inadvertently  mention a competitor.

In 2006, ON Semiconductor completed a $105 Million acquisition of **LSI** Logic Corporation’s Gresham...

https://www.onsemi.com/company/news-media/press-announcements/en/on-semiconductor-completes-105-million-acquisition-of-lsi-logic-corporation-s-gresham-ore-8-inch-wafer-fab

It's purely speculation, but maybe the term LSI means more to ON semi within their organisation than it does to those outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the ON website, you will see that they refer to all of their single chip devices as LSI, not just battery monitors. Therefore I believe that nanofarad is correct in that LSI stands for Large Scale Integration or perhaps a slight variation unique to ON.